# How can I save the user input on eclipse console to save in a file?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, console-application, user-input

I've just started learning. So please bear my mistakes.

I wanted to create a program in which I can ask the User to write into the console and the User's input will be saved into a text file. In short, **Write a program which will create, write and save a file.**

It's basic one, can experts please provide me some alternatives of this program which look like a advanced one, any modulation through which I can improve or expands the functioning of the program. Then that would be a great teaching for me. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    File myfile = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Myfilenew.txt");

    if(!myfile.exists())
        myfile.createNewFile();
    else
        myfile.delete();


    try {
        PrintWriter pwrt = new PrintWriter(myfile);
        pwrt.println("This is my first java created text file");
        System.out.println("Enter the data to be writter into the text file"+"\n"+"Type 'End' to save and exit the file: "+"\n");

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            if(!sc.hasNext("End"))
                pwrt.println(sc.nextLine());
            else
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
        pwrt.close();
        sc.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: If you are asking how to improve a working program you should ask on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449 for correction. I didn't knew.